# I can't find "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" in Visual Studio 2022 (free download)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022, basic

I used VB6 a couple of decades ago, now I need VB again. Got the free download from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/. Started the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-a-visual-basic-winform-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022. Step 3 says to click the "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" selection.  That is not on my list (see below, which is not the same as the other thread in stackoverflow with a similar title).  What am I missing?
[image: My "Create a new project" screen]
[image: Installer parameters]
[image: The list filtered on the language Visual Basic]

Comment: Could you confirm in Visual Studio Installer that the ".NET desktop development" workload checkbox is checked?

Comment: It is indeed checked.

Comment: Try filtering on VB as a language in the list to make it a little more manageable?

Comment: FIltered on VB: Not there (see image on main submission).

Answer (score 1):

Gee, something has gone wrong here. I would try to un-check the .net desktop development. Let it update. And then close, re-open, and then try adding .net desktop development again.

I have all of these selected:

[image]

And then when I go create new project, then I can filter and see this:

[image]

Note in above, you want to choose the 2nd choice (.net framework - always).

Comment: Yeah, I added a few more modules that seems very loosely related, and apparently one of them (I do not know which) worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it looks like they are making us work a bit harder to get the older bits and parts installed. but, to be fair, they do have good support for this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio Installer, then make sure you select ".NET desktop development" option.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMOzj.png)